# r ggplot error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (250000):

Tags: r, ggplot2

I run sample code to generate a graph to describe Markov Chain Monte Carlo.
https://github.com/davharris/mcmc-tutorial
However I encounter the following exception thrown by the last line of code.
"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (250000): x, y"

The code has been listed in the following.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
lik = function(x, y) {
    dnorm(x - 3) * dnorm(y - x + 2)
}

grid.values = seq(min.x, max.x, length = 500)
grid = expand.grid(x = grid.values, y = grid.values)
z = lik(grid$x, grid$y)

gaussian.plot = ggplot(data = grid, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) + scale_fill_gradient2() + coord_equal()

gaussian.plot

maxit = 50

samples = matrix(NA, nrow = maxit, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y")))
samples[1, ] = c(0, 0)  # start at 0,0

for (i in 2:maxit) {

    # propose a new sample point
    proposal = samples[i - 1, ] + rnorm(2, mean = 0, sd = 1)

    # Compare its likelihood with the current position
    old.lik = lik(samples[i - 1, "x"], samples[i - 1, "y"])
    new.lik = lik(proposal["x"], proposal["y"])

    ratio = new.lik/old.lik

    # flip a coin and accept the new proposal with probability min(ratio, 1)
    if (rbinom(1, size = 1, prob = min(ratio, 1))) {
        samples[i, ] = proposal
    } else {
        # If you don't accept the proposal, just keep what you had in the     last
        # time step
        samples[i, ] = samples[i - 1, ]
    }

}


gaussian.plot + geom_path(mapping = aes(x = samples[, "x"], y = samples[, "y"]), 
color = "orange") + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = samples[, "x"], y = samples[, 
"y"]))
```

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce when the data is not included. Quote: `Error in seq(min.x, max.x, length = 500) : object 'min.x' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`samples`is a matrix, convert it to a dataframe with `as.data.frame()` so that `ggplot2`can work with it.
Since you want to have points that are from a different dataframe than the one used for the top plot which is `gaussian.plot`, you need to define where the data comes from.
This should work:

```
 gaussian.plot + geom_path(data=samples,aes(x = x, y = y),color = "orange") + geom_point(data=samples,aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.